# View at the bottom in a UIScrollView, with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm setting up content in a scroll view with autolayout. The objects in the scrollview are pinned top-to-bottom to the previous one, so that they are under one another. I have a footer view that is added at the end, below these objects.

Here's the catch: when there's few content, the contentView will be smaller than the screen height, so the footer view will appear somewhere in the middle of the screen (which is the normal behavior). But I'd like to prevent that, and make the view stay somewhere at the bottom.

In other words, I would like to setup a double constraint like:

```
Put this view below all the objects in the scrollview 
AND
keep this view at a distance of max [some number] of the bottom of the screen
```

In a way that both constraints are always satisfied:

- If the height of the content is bigger than the screen, then the view appears at the bottom, after scrolling down
- If the height is smaller, then the view is "pinned" to the bottom of the screen, leaving a space relatively big between the bottom of the content and the top of this view

How can I achieve that with AutoLayout?

Comment: See my answer for an Auto-Layout-only solution.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Fairly easy to do with Auto-Layout only... no code required.

The key is to use a "content view" to hold the elements, and a `greater-than-or-equal` constraint between your "bottom" element and your "footer" view.

In this image, yellow is the main view, green is the scroll view, blue is the content view, the labels are gray and the footer view is pink.

[image]

- Start with a fresh view controller
- add a scroll view, normal constraints (I used `20` all the way around, so we can see the frame)
- add a `UIView` to the scrollView - this will be our "content view"
- constrain contentView Top/Bottom/Leading/Trailing all equal to `0` to the scrollView
- constrain both the Width and Height of the contentView equal to the scrollView
- add your elements - here I used 3 labels
- constrain the labels as usual... I used:

  - LabelA - Top/Leading/Trailing all at `20`, vertical spacing to LabelB of `60`
  - LabelB - Leading/Trailing at `20`, vertical spacing to LabelC of `60`
  - LabelC - Leading/Trailing at `20`
- LabelC is also set to `Number of Lines: 0` so it will expand with multiple lines of text
- Add a `UIView` as a "footer view" (I stuck a label in it)
- constrain the footerView Leading/Trailing/Bottom all at `20` (so we can see the frame)
- either set a Height constraint on footerView, or use its content to constrain its height
- add a Vertical Spacing constraint from LabelC to footerView, and set it to `>= 40`
- last step, change the Height constraint of contentView to `Priority: 250`

Now, as you expand/contract the height of LabelC, the footerView will keep *at least* 40-pts of vertical space. When LabelC gets big enough to "push" footerView below the bottom, scrollView will become scrollable.

Results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I missed any steps... You can get my storyboard here - see what's different, if anything: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/7576d0710163ae4f53f7508c1fed35f6

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Magic answer, works like a charm;) A bottle of wine for that guy

Comment: It worked also for me, nice answer, easy to apply, working properly. TOP

Comment: Textbook explanation backed by crafted images. Thank you so much!

Comment: Works great! I was looking for a solution to this problem for so long! Thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: This was supper helpful to me. I was able to replicate this using programatic views also

Answer (score 1):

you need to check ContentSize of scrollView and modify FooterView Top Constraint with the required Value

**My class code**

```
import UIKit

class scrollViewDrag: UIViewController
{
    /// ScrollView Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

    /// Footer View top spacing constraint
    @IBOutlet weak var footerViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    /// Used for ScrollView Height
    var screenHeight = CGFloat()

    /// Did Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    /// Function used to check for height 
    func checkForHeight(){
        /// Get scrollView Height
        screenHeight = mainScrollView.frame.size.height

        /// Check contentSize Height ?
        if mainScrollView.contentSize.height >= screenHeight {
            /// When ScrollView is having height greater than your scrollView Height
            /// Footer will scroll along other Views
        }
        else{
            /// Issue Case
            let spacingValue = screenHeight-mainScrollView.contentSize.height
            footerViewTopConstraint.constant = spacingValue
        }
    }

    /// Call the height function in DidAppear
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        checkForHeight()
    }
}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

I had used Four View with Equal Heights And at last a footerView is attached as Fourth View

**FooterView Top Constraint**

[image]

Top constraint used as `footerViewTopConstraint`

**Output**

Case 1 - Size is greater than scrollView Height

[image]

Case 2 - Expected Output

[image]

Comment: This is indeed working! Although I thought there would be a way to achieve that using only constraints, without manual computation.

Answer (score 1):

For scrollview with `Content Layout Guides` and `Frame Layout Guides`, the above solutions might not work. But the same can be achieved by following these steps:

1. Add scrollview to your main view. Add leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints with the superview (ignore the content size ambiguity errors for height and width)

[image: step-1]

2. Add container view to your scrollview.
3. Add top, bottom, leading trailing constraints of container view to scrollview's `ContentLayoutGuides`.

[image: step-3]

4. Add `Equal Widths` constraint b/w container view and `FrameLayoutGuide`. This will fix the content horizontally and will allow vertical scroll.
5. Add `Equal Height` constraint b/w container view and `FrameLayoutGuide` and set the priority to 999. This will allow the container view to maintain a height equal to scrollview when content size is smaller but at the same time will allow to scroll when content size is greater than the scrollview's height.

[image: step-5]

Now lets say you have two views, a UILabel and a UIButton. You want your label to be fixed at the top and grow when it has more text. And you want your button to stay fixed at the bottom even if text is single line and maintain a distance (e.g 100 points) with the label when label grows. Follow the steps to achieve this:

1. Add a `UILabel` in your container view, give it top, leading and trailing constraints and make no. of lines equal to zero.

[image: step-2-1]

2. Add a `UIButton` in your container view, give it bottom, leading and trailing.

[image: step2-2]

3. Add a vertical spacing constraint with `Greater Than or Equal` relation and a constant value of the min spacing required. At this point you are done but to satisfy Xcode, we need to add one more dummy constraint which we will remove at build time.
4. Set constraint vertical spacing b/w label and button and set priority to 750. Check `Remove at build time`. This is a dummy constraint just to satisfy Xcode.

[image: step2-3]

Here is the output with single line text:

[image: output-1]

And this is how it will look with very long text:

[image: output-2]