# How to add a dynamic height/space element in a UIScrollView using storyboards and auto-layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm using storyboards to build my `UI` and I've reached a stage where I can't go any further. I'm trying to make a `UIVew` or `constraint` (bottom view's top `constraint` to the bottom `constraint` of the view above) to have a dynamic height or to be adjustable automatically (red view). I can't use a fixed height/size value because of the different screen sizes.

All I want to achieve is to place the bottom view (with violet) in the bottom of the screen in a way that is always in the bottom and if the screen's height is smaller than the content inside, then it should be placed below the turquoise colored view (red view's height becomes 0).

I've tried to add for the red view a `height >= 10`, now Xcode complained about "`UIScrollView` doesn't have an y position or height". I've tried many many other options: adding `center X`, `center Y` value for the `contentView`, made the `contentView`'s height to be equal to the `Safe Area`'s height (low priority @250).

[image]

Comment: In my approach, I will use `static cell` + `UITableViewControlller` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Here is a complete example to accomplish pretty much exactly what you've described: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50864054/6257435

Comment: @DonMag - I've implemented and it's working! The key here was the `>=` constraint between the bottom view and the view above.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian - good. I'll mark this as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can se the red view's height constraint a lower priority (low) that of the purple bottom and height constraints(high).