# UIScrollView/UIStackView - stretch when content is too short

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints, uistackview

I have a storyboard-based UI with UIScrollView which contains vertical UIStackView, which in turn contains various form elements (dynamically rendered). The last view in the stack is a "button panel."

My problem is that, while scrolling works as expected, especially when content is taller than the phone window, I cannot get it to fill the window when there are only few elements - instead, I get a short view with space under the button panel (see the image below: scroll view has green background, button panel has purple background).

[image: screenshot]

**Basically, I'm trying to find a way to tell the button panel (a simple UIView) to stretch enough to fill the rest of the height on-screen if the rest of the content is short, but I'm having a problem doing so.** Am I missing something?

Here's how the constraints are set:

- UIScrollView - sides are attached to safe area sides
- UIStackView - sides are attached to Superview sides, widths are equal
- Several container views in stack view without explicit constraints (those are set by dynamic content)
- Last UIView in stack view is a button area. Buttons inside it set constraints on position within that view (basically position to the leading and top edges).

Help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: Do you want your buttons aligned to the bottom of the scroll view frame, unless there is enough content at which point the "button panel" would scroll down out of view? Or do you want the "button panel" ***always*** at the very bottom, with just the content above it scrollable?

Comment: I intended for the former - button panel being part of the scrollable content.

Comment: OK - looks like this is what you're after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50864054/6257435 ... if that is your issue, comment here and we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I ended up taking the lower panel (as well as the upper one) outside of UIScrollView and attaching them to the respective superview edges. Should've started with this from the get go.