UIScrollView: Button always at the bottom, unless content is too big, then it should be further down
I try to get a layout with some labels below each other in a UIScrollView, e.g. title and description. A button should be at the very bottom of the view. When the content is too big (e.g. too much description) the button should scroll out of sight and be next to the descriptiontext. I can't get it to work though, my latest try was the following:
I also get this behavior which I cannot explain: 
//
//  KitchenSinkView.swift
//  MBViews
//
//  Created by Stefan Walkner on 26.04.24.
//

import UIKit

class KitchenSink: UIView {

    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let contentLabel = UILabel()
    private let actionButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .white

        // Setup scrollView
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(scrollView)

        // Setup titleLabel
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.text = "Title"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
        titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        // Setup contentLabel
        contentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentLabel.text = """
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        asdf
        """
        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        contentLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        contentLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        // Setup actionButton
        actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        actionButton.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        actionButton.backgroundColor = .red
        actionButton.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        // Add subviews to scrollView
        scrollView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentLabel)
        scrollView.addSubview(actionButton)
    }
    private var buttonBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20),

            contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            contentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            contentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20),

            actionButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            actionButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            actionButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])

        buttonBottomConstraint = actionButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        buttonBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        adjustButtonPosition()
    }

    private func adjustButtonPosition() {
        let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
        let contentHeight = titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height + contentLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height + 60 // total vertical padding + button height

        if contentHeight < scrollViewHeight {
            // If the content + padding is less than the height of the scroll view, anchor button to bottom of the screen
            buttonBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
            buttonBottomConstraint = actionButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
            buttonBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
        } else {
            // Content is enough to require scrolling, anchor button to content
            buttonBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
            buttonBottomConstraint = actionButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
            buttonBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
        }
    }
}

class KitchenSinkViewController: UIViewController {

    private var customView: KitchenSink!

    override func loadView() {
        customView = KitchenSink()
        view = customView
    }
}

#Preview {
    KitchenSinkViewController()
}



Is this what you're going for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50864054/6257435

yes, but I get the behavior in the GIF then

Did you try the code I posted in my answer below?

Also, I don't get the behavior in you GIF when using the Storyboard from that linked answer.

Here is a code-only version of the storyboard answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50864054/6257435
The approach is:

use a "content" view as the base view of the scroll view
constrain title and content labels as we normally would inside the "content" view
constrain the button leading/trailing/bottom as we normally would inside the "content" view
constrain the Top of the button >= to the Bottom of the content label
constrain the Height of the "content" view Equal to the Height of the scroll view's frame layout guide, with a less-than-required priority, and >= to the Height of the scroll view's frame layout guide. This will

allow the "content" view to grow taller, but also
prevent the "content" view height from shrinking shorter than the scroll view



So, as the height of the contentLable grows...

if there is still room between its Bottom and the Button's Top, no change
when it gets tall enough, it will "push" the Button down, which will expand the Height of the "content" view, which will allow vertical scrolling

So - example code:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var customView: KitchenSink!
    
    override func loadView() {
        customView = KitchenSink()
        view = customView
    }
    
}

class KitchenSink: UIView {
    
    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let contentLabel = UILabel()
    private let addButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    
    private let myContentView = UIView()
    
    // just for this example, so we can "grow/shrink" the contentLabel
    private var minLines: Int = 6
    private var maxLines: Int = 15
    private var numLines: Int = 6
    private var isAdding: Bool = true
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {

        // Setup titleLabel
        titleLabel.text = "Title"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 36)
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        // Setup contentLabel
        contentLabel.text = Array(1...numLines).map { "Line \($0)" }.joined(separator: "\n")
        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        contentLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        // let's use a large font so we don't have to click the button too many times
        contentLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 48)
        
        // Setup actionButton
        addButton.setTitle("Add Line", for: .normal)
        addButton.backgroundColor = .yellow
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        for v in [titleLabel, contentLabel, addButton] {
            v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            myContentView.addSubview(v)
        }

        myContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(myContentView)
        
        // Setup scrollView
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(scrollView)

    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        
        let g = safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        // "content" view height equal to frame layout guide height
        //      priority .defaultHigh, so it can be broken
        // this will prevent the button from "moving up"
        let mcvHeight = myContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.heightAnchor)
        mcvHeight.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of scroll view to safe area
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leftAnchor),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.rightAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            // title label top/leading/trailing to "content" view
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            
            // content label leading/trailing to "content" view, top to titleLabel bottom
            contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            contentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            contentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            
            // button top greater-than-or-equal to content label bottom
            addButton.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // button leading/trailing/bottom to "content" view
            addButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            addButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            addButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myContentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),

            // "content" view all 4 sides to content layout guide
            myContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor),
            myContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
            myContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
            myContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor),
            
            // "content" view width to frame layout guide
            myContentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // "content" view height greater-than-or-equal to frame layout guide
            //  so it can grow
            myContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: fg.heightAnchor),
            
            // activate mcv height constraint
            mcvHeight,
            
        ])
        
        // so we can see the framing
        self.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        myContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
    @objc func btnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isAdding {
            numLines += 1
        } else {
            numLines -= 1
        }
        // update text in contentLabel
        contentLabel.text = Array(1...numLines).map { "Line \($0)" }.joined(separator: "\n")

        // toggle adding / removing lines on button tap
        if numLines == maxLines {
            isAdding = false
            addButton.setTitle("Remove Line", for: .normal)
        } else if numLines == minLines {
            isAdding = true
            addButton.setTitle("Add Line", for: .normal)
        }

        // let's auto-scroll to keep the button visible
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            let r: CGRect = .init(x: 0.0, y: self.scrollView.contentSize.height - 1.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(r, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
}

